# Is there any way to know that when the user is killing application in background and foreground both?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification, uiapplicationdelegate

I am developing application in which push notification functionality is enabled/implemented. When user kills the application, user has to login again, as after the user kills the app, app is logged out as we are not preserving the user login state. But user is still receiving Push notifications when app is killed and app is in logged out state.

Is there any way to know that when the user is killing application?
because applicationWillTerminate method will not be called in every situation.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` in app delegate?

Comment: ya @SkBorhanUddin i tried it, but thats not fullfill my need, what i want is to when user force kill the application at that time i need to do some task and restrict user form receiving push notification furhter.